# how to use IIS published Restfull service url in another computer

Tags: json, restful-url

How can I use my Restfull service that I published on my local IIS(windows computer) in another computer(Mac) for ipad application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to deploy the service on a Mac? Can't you just access your current IIS from the IPad? You would have to install Mono on your Mac in order to get the service running...

Comment: Hi Dunken, I created a restfull service(json) in VS2013 on windows and I want to use this url for my ipad appication but i am developing ipad app in mac computer.Is this possible with Mono? If yes,can you tell me the steps to do

Comment: I would keep your restful service on Windows but access it from your IPad app. You don't need to move your service on your MAC.

Comment: I don't want to move service.My question is how to use that service for ipad app in another computer means my url is  "http://localhost/RestfullService/Service1.svc/getdetails"  or       "http://myipaddress/RestfullService/Service1.svc/getdetails" .Is this url is accessible on other computer(other computer ip address is different)

Comment: You need to use IP-address (e.g. 173.194.35.100) or hostname (e.g. www.google.com) of your Windows-PC instead of localhost in order to access your service.

Comment: Ok,Thanks. I will do like this

Comment: Hi Dunken, I did the same but in mac computer my service url "http://myipaddress/restfullService/Service1.svc/getdetails" is not working."google chrome could not connect to 'myipaddress'"

Comment: Configure/turn off your firewall.

Comment: I turned off the firewall but still not connecting

Comment: can you ping your windows PC?